# Why doesn't my AsyncTask execute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to read data form a website in an Async-Task.
But, although I call `execute()`, it doesn't enter the Async-Task.
Not even the `preExecute()` method is called, at least the Log entry, that would say so, doesn't appear.

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mResult; //This Result will be returned by FetchDataTask()



    private final String LOG_TAG = NewFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    // fetch data from example.com and show them in textView
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FetchDataTask fetchDataTask = new FetchDataTask();

        fetchDataTask.execute("http://example.com");


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new,container,false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(mResult);


        return rootView;


    }

    public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String >{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchDataTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"onPreExecute()"); //This Log-entry doesn't appear, why??
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings){
            //http-connection:
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            String result = "";

            try{
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                //read data:

                if(inputStream==null){
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"There is nothin'");
                } else {
                     bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line + "\n";
                    }
                }




            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            } finally {
                if(httpURLConnection!=null){
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if(bufferedReader != null){
                    try{
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }catch (final IOException e){
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }



            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"doInBackground()");
            return result;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string){
            mResult=null;

            if(string!=null){
                mResult=string;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the activity containing your fragment or have you checked the onCreateView() is called ?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF onCreateView() is working...

Comment: unrelated to the non-execution of your asynctask, but `textView.setText(mResult);` is not going to work. You are not doing that when the asynctask is finished, you are doing it immediatly, when the task is not even started.

Comment: @taxus1 Do you have a logcat of the execution. Can not figure our why it is not at least starting by reading the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to why you aren't seeing the message, are you making the Fragment class and adding to an Activity? Otherwise, that problem can't be reproduced.

> `// This Result will be returned by FetchDataTask()`

**False**. That isn't how asynchronous code works. You are setting the TextView to `null`, and not waiting for the AsyncTask to finish.

Instead, just store the textview in a field

```
private TextView textView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new,container,false);
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    FetchDataTask fetchDataTask = new FetchDataTask();
    fetchDataTask.execute("http://example.com");

    return rootView;
}
```

And **later**, set the text

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string){

    if(string!=null){
        textView.setText(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome. I might suggest learning about the other HTTP libraries like Volley (or Retrofit if you have JSON data) since they are nicer to work with than AsyncTasks.

Answer (score -1):

Change, `public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>` into `public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` to make signature similar to your asynctask implementation.

Also, add `setRetainInstance(true)` in fragments `onCreate()` to retain view while orientation changes happen. Just a best practice.

And finally, let you have `newFragment` instance in activity, thus call `newFragment.startFetching()`, where you have something like,

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {
    public void startFetching() {
        FetchDataTask fetchDataTask = new FetchDataTask();
        fetchDataTask.execute("http://example.com");
    }
    ...
}
```

reference: https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/2480065

Comment: Could you explain what would be the difference?

Comment: he must implement onProgressUpdate() with Integer parameter to make signature matched.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso The second data type in <...> stands for the onProgessUpdate()-Method, which I don't use, so it's sensible to change it into Void

Comment: But a AsyncTask would never stop working because of that.

Comment: I doesn't seem to make any difference anyway